# Nuxt: Redirect to Google login without pressing a "Login with Google" Button

Tags: nuxt.js, google-signin, nuxt-auth

I'm trying to implement a google login only Nuxt App. When the user is not authenticated, the app should automatically be redirected to the google login page and should afterwards be redirected to the restricted page.

My scheme looks like this:

```js
auth: {
  strategies: {
    social: {
      scheme: 'oauth2',
      endpoints: {
        authorization: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        token: 'http://localhost:4000/api/auth/google/token',
        refresh: 'http://localhost:4000/api/auth/google/refresh'
      },
      user: {
        autoFetch: false,
      },
      token: {
        property: 'access_token',
        type: 'Bearer',
      },
      refreshToken: {
        property: 'refresh_token',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
      },
      responseType: 'code',
      clientId: <clientId>,
      scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
      state: 'UNIQUE_AND_NON_GUESSABLE',
      codeChallengeMethod: '',
      responseMode: '',
      acrValues: '',
    }
  }
},
```

I've tried using the `this.$auth.loginWith('social')` call inside the `created` or `mounted` function calls of my login page. This redirects the user to the google login after being redirected to the login page. Unfortunately after google routing me back to my login page, the redirect is also executed, leaving me in a circuit loop between my login page and the google login page.

Is there a preferred way of achieving what I want or are there any workarounds?

Comment: Yes I've tried, but it didn't support my specific setup. Nevertheless using the specific nuxt-auth strategy won't fix my particular problem in my opionion.

Comment: This is handled for you. First off, use the [`auth` middleware globally](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/middleware). Then, set the [`redirect` key](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options/#redirect) to set the places you want your user to go regarding various authentication states.